# Capture OpenLayers.Layer.Image 404 Not found as an error message

Tags: openlayers

Is there a way to know when an OpenLayers.Layer.Image fails to find the image, i.e. returns a 404 (Not Found)?

I tried adding a listener for "loadend", but it comes back looking ok - unless there is something deep within the event object that I'm missing.

```
myLayer.events.register("loadend", myLayer, function(e)
{
   console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem - IMHO it's not possible to track status of  content